# MySQL is very slow when querying a row that doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I have a User table with more than 100m rows, there is no partition:

```
    create table User {
        user_id int primary key auto_increment,
        user_email varchar(50) unique,
        ...//no more than 20 columns
    }  ENGINE=MyISAM
```

most of time it's ok with following sql:

```
select user_id, .... from User where user_email=?
```

but if I gave an email address that does not exist in DB, then it could be very slow, maybe more that 1s.

what the problem could be?

=======update==========
the database has a slave, I just tested that the SQL is pretty fast even if no such record.

is it because the database run for a long time(for about 3 years)?

Comment: Whether to create an index

Comment: user_email varchar(50) unique, this is already an index

Comment: you use MyISAM maybe some locks appear while you quering?

Comment: @disorderdev Try `ANALYZE TABLE User;`, see if this helps.

Comment: @fancyPants how long will analyze take for 100m records, the data size is about 20G

Comment: I don't know. Last time I did this, it took about 1 second, but I got one hell of a machine standing here. And it depends on a lot of factors.